# Método de classe retorna null

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Tenho uma class à qual passo `data` mas quando chamo o método da classe essa `data` aparece como `null`. Porquê?

```
class Test {

    constructor(data) {
        this.myData = data;
    }

    MyFunction = () => {
        return this.myData;
    };
}
```

Quando instancio essa Classe a consola retorna-me `null`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var t = new Test({"data1", "data2", "data3"});
    //
    console.log( t.MyFunction() );

</script>
```

Comment: Provavelmente queres `MyFunction (){` em vez de `MyFunction = () => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Métodos de classes devem ser declaradas com `: () => {` ou abreviando diretamente para `(){`... ou seja como faríamos num objeto.

para além disso, a sintaxe desse `data` que passas à classe quando instancias está errado. Estás a usar `{'string', 'string'}`... acho que queres `[]` para teres uma array.

Exemplo:

```js
class Test {

  constructor(data) {
    this.myData = data;
  }

  MyFunction() {
    return this.myData;
  };
}

var t = new Test([
  "data1",
  "data2",
  "data3"
]);

console.log(t.MyFunction());
```

Comment: O problema era uma das minhas funções estava estática e nao deveria, mas obrigada pela ajuda